# $X$ and $Y$ have a joint normal distribution with unity variance, zero mean, and correlation = $0.5$ -- what is $P(X > 2Y | X > 0)$?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, bivariate-distributions

I know how to find $P(X > 2Y | X > 0)$ for the case where $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I would use a graphical approach. It would come out to be $\frac{\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(0.5)}{\pi}$.

With a non-zero correlation, the bivariate distribution is no longer radially symmetric, and I believe for a correlation of $0.5$, it would stretch out the distribution along the $y = x$ line. How can I apply the graphical approach here?

Comment: Hint: Show that $X-2Y, X$ are uncorrelated normal random variables.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I can show that from the definition of covariance and find that it's zero. But why am I assessing $X-2Y$ and $X$?

Comment: It allows you to rewrite $$P(X > 2Y | X > 0) = P(X-2Y > 0 | X > 0) = P(X-2Y > 0)$$ since $X-2Y$ and $X$ are independent.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Ohh I get it. But what if we changed the 2 to another constant $c$? In that case, we wouldn't be able to show that $X - cY$ and $X$ are uncorrelated for any $c$

Comment: We'd still use $X-2Y$ and $X$, but we'd want to properly normalize, so the solution would look a lot more like heropup's (ultimately using your "graphical approach")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the joint mean is $(\mu_X, \mu_Y) = (0,0)$, otherwise the question becomes much more difficult.  Then let

$$X = U, \quad Y = \frac{U + \sqrt{3} V}{2},$$

or equivalently

$$U = X, \quad V = \frac{2Y - X}{\sqrt{3}}.$$

Under this transformation, $(U, V)$ will be bivariate standard normal.  Then the desired probability becomes

$$\Pr[X > 2Y \mid X > 0] = \Pr[\sqrt{3} V < 0 \mid U > 0] = \frac{1}{2}$$ trivially.  The main computation is showing that $(U,V)$ has identity covariance matrix.

Comment: Why is main computation showing $U,V$ have identity covariance? Aren't they, by definition, IID standard normal? I believe the expressions you have for $X$ and $Y$ are obtained from a cholesky factorization of the covariance matrix of $X$ and $Y$, and then you can introduce 2 IID standard normals to form X and Y. So it seems those U and V are by definition have an identity covariance matrix?

Comment: @user5965026 Yes, that is correct.  Identity covariance = IID standard normal (since the original $X, Y$ have zero mean).  The Cholesky factorization *is* the main computation I am referring to.  It's not hard, but compared to the trivial probability calculation, it is the detail that I have left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Is there an intuitive way to remember the 2x2 cholesky decomposition for the covariance matrix? It's a simple formula, but everytime I need it, I have to search it on Google or spend 5min deriving it.